# Ajax. On Ajax success call same ajax function one more time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is what i tried.

```
                    tjq.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>getCmsHotel?t=<?php echo $traceId;?>',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    encoding:"UTF-8",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    traditional: true,
                    async: true,
                    error: function (request, error) {
                        searchApiCount++;
                        hotelssearchObj.reloadFunctions(searchApiCount);
                        return false;
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                      //alert(data.status);         
        
                        if(data.status == 'FAILURE'){
                            //searchresults = data;
                            searchApiCount++;
                            hotelssearchObj.reloadFunctions(searchApiCount);
                            return false;
                        }else if(data.status == 'SUCCESS'){
                            var recalajx = '2'; 
                             if(recalajx =='2' && recalajx!=3){
                                 recalajx ='3';
                                tjq.ajax(this); 
                             }
                            alert(recalajx); 
                             
                            tjq('.searchresultsDiv').remove();
                            hotelsresults = data;
                            //hotelssearchObj.hotelsResults(data);
                            
                            gblStartCount        = 1;
                            gblHotelData         = tjq.extend(true, {}, data);
                            gblHotelDisplayData = tjq.extend(true, {}, data);
                            hotelssearchObj.hotelsResults(gblHotelDisplayData);
                            searchApiCount++;
                            hotelssearchObj.reloadFunctions(searchApiCount);
                                            
                            tjq("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                        }    
                    }
                });
```

This code calling multiple times. Am trying to call tjq.ajax(this); only once  after 1st ajax SUCCESS.

when tried to alert getting 3 but still axaj calling for multi times.

How to stop this can some help!

Comment: hi can some one tell how to achieve

Comment: Can you add your complete ajax code ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping ok

Comment: Initialize a variable and increment it on every success response. Then check if the variable value is less than number of success response.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki i tired same but no luck

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to put the Ajax call in a function, and check how many times it has been called with a counter. If the counter is less than 2, call the function again.

here's an example:

```
ajaxCall();

function ajaxCall(counter = 0) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    success: function() {
      counter++
      if (counter < 2) {
        ajaxCall(counter);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Global counter or otherwise we can pass the counter as parameter to the recursive function

Comment: @Lepanto this is a better solution, I have updated my answer.